# PHP preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

For some reason I keep getting this error in my PHP for `preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` even though I have a delimiter in my preg_match regexp, so what is going on? This is happening for each and ever preg_match function i call in my code. I don't know what is wrong with it.

```
 $return = preg_match($string, "/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around. The pattern comes before. Try this:

```
$return = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $string);
```

Also, the docs can be read [here](https://www.php.net/preg_match).